# Does Epplus support Excel 2013?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, excel-charts, epplus-4

I have a excel file, which is created in Excel 2013 MS package.
It contains Numeric values and charts. I had do open the file and added new rows and then while saving the file , got this error in C#.net

> This property or method is not supported for a Chartsheet

Could anyone tell me that the limitation on epplus,upto what version of excel epplus will support?

Thanks,

Comment: I working witch c# and Epplus and Excel 2013 - it works great! What is your problem with Epplus?

Comment: Have you tried downloading and debugging the sourcecode of EPP? This might give you a clue about the actual problem here.

Comment: Can we see the code that triggers the error? There are `ExcelWorksheet` and `ExcelChartsheet` objects - sounds like you might have conflated the two? I'd certainly advocate letting the StackOverfow community see your own code before atttempting to debug EPPlus code

Answer (score 3):

Chartsheet is a special type of sheet which contains a chart only, EPPlus does not support Chartsheet, instead of Chartsheet you can just add the your chart to the normal sheet.